# Tuning AMCL's diff-corrected and omni-corrected odom models

Tags: navigation, odometry, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just read the discussion on `amcl`'s incorrect odometry models. See:

- [http://answers.ros.org/question/54467](http://answers.ros.org/question/54467/is-amcls-implementation-of-the-odometry-model-correct/)
- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/20

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to properly tune the parameters `odom_alpha1` through `odom_alpha5` (relative to the "incorrect" models). The consensus seems to be that the old defaults (`0.2`) don't work properly with the corrected models. I tried a few things, such as lowering them by an order of magnitude, but didn't get decent results.

PS. To be more specific, here's my experience with a made-up omni-drive robot in Stage (`drive "omni"`) and the `omni-corrected` odom model. If I tell the `DWAPlanner` to treat the robot as nonholonomic (`holonomic_robot: false`), then AMCL does OK. If I let it command lateral  velocities (`holonomic_robot: true` and same `y` velocity params as `x` params), all hell breaks loose. Interestingly, it's mainly the position that's off, not the orientation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227811/tuning-amcl%27s-diff-corrected-and-omni-corrected-odom-models/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found some numbers in this test config: [amcl/test/small_loop_crazy_driving_prg_corrected.xml](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/amcl/test/small_loop_crazy_driving_prg_corrected.xml)

They seem to be in the right ballpark for my omnidirectional platform.

```
<param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.005"/>
<param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.005"/>
<param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.010"/>
<param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.005"/>
<param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.003"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7